# Baking ratio for waffles!

Tags: baking, waffle, ratio

What is the ratio between flour, sugar, fat, liquid, and egg for waffles? 
I searched up "baking ratios" and "cooking ratios" but the closest thing that came up was for pancakes. Now, I know pancakes and waffles have different compositions.

I really want to make my own recipe for orange flavored waffles, and want to do so using the help of a golden ratio.

Comment: Waffles just need more fat (oil) so they won't stick to the waffle maker.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot find a "golden ratio" as there is no such thing for something as diverse as "waffles":

- Brussels Waffles
- Liège Waffles
- Butter waffles
- Vanilla waffles
- Blueberry waffles
- Honey Waffles
- ...

Just take a recipe for waffles that resembles the kind of waffles you want to make and substitute one ingredient for another (In this case, I'd start with a blueberry waffle recipe and change the blueberries with oranges cut up in cubes as big as blueberries).